# Can I enter Germany from the UK before my Family Reunion Visa starts?

Tags: germany, eu, eu-spouses, dependent-visa

I am Colombian, I have a residence card in the UK and recently got a family reunion visa type D to move with my EU-citizen partner to Germany.

So, I am in the UK and because of the current situation, we'll need to travel to Germany 2 days before my Family reunion visa starts. Is that going to be a problem?

I know that just with my UK residence card I can enter Germany, but if they stop us and ask why are we travelling, we'll have to say that we are planning to live there and, presumably, they are going to ask for a visa to do that, which I have, but it won't be valid quite yet.

I also want to make sure this won't get me in trouble when I go to get the residence permit.

Comment: Since you are traveling with your EU-Citizen partner, you will have no problem.

Comment: Where are you "already in the EU"?  Is your partner German?  Is your visa really a "family reunion" visa, or is it a visa for the family member of an EU citizen?  It may sound like the same thing, but they are legally distinct (among other differences, the family reunion visa is a type D visa while the visa for a family member of an EU citizen is a type C visa).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @phoog I have updated the question to add the following details: the visa is type D and I am in the UK.